# Haskell- Função de substituição numa lista

Tags: haskell

Sabem se existe alguma função predefinida no haskell que dado um elemento, o substitui por um outro elemento de uma determinada posição da lista.
Por exemplo:

```
func 1 2 [1,2,3,4]  
[1,2,1,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisa alterar elementos em um determinado índice, listas não são a estrutura para isso. Você poderia utilizar `Seq` do `Data.Sequence`, nesse caso a função que você está procurando é `update :: Int -> a -> Seq a -> Seq a`.

Para fazer o que você queria no seu exemplo usando o update ficaria assim:

```
> import Data.Sequence
> update 2 1 $ fromList [1,2,3,4]
fromList [1,2,1,4]
```

Para mais informações veja esse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133361/haskell-replace-element-in-list